# Проблема в том что программа удаляет лишь последнее слово. Внизу дан пример

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, поток-ввода

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <cstdlib>
 using namespace std;

 string sortString(string &str) 
 { 
 sort(str.begin(), str.end()); 
 return str; 
 }  

  int main () 
  {
  string word, line; 
  vector<string>words;
  string wrd2, str1, str2;
  ifstream myfirst("first.txt");
  if (myfirst.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfirst,line) )
    {   
        if (line!="") { 
            istringstream ss(line); 
            char space = ' ';
            while (getline(ss, word, space)) {
                words.push_back(word);
            }
            string wrd = words[words.size()-1];
                for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
                    str1 += wrd[i];
                }
        } 
    }
 myfirst.close();
 }
 else cout << "Unable to open file"; 


 ofstream mysecond ("second.txt");
 if (mysecond.is_open())
 {
    for(int i = 0; i < words.size()-1; i++){
        wrd2 = words[i];
        for(int j=0; j < 3; j++){
            str2 += wrd2[j];
        }

        if(str1 != str2){
            mysecond << wrd2 << " ";
        }   
        str2 = "";  
    }
   mysecond.close();
      cout<<"Done! Go to second file ";
     }
     else cout << "Unable to open file";
     return 0;
    }
```

Дан например файл (text.txt) . Этот файл нужно вызвать и удалить те слова, в которых первые три буквы совпадают с начальными буквами последнего слова строки.Между словами могут быть несколько пробелов. А потом нужно создать новый файл (newfile.txt ) и написать новые данные. Например

first.txt:

Programming and coding, program

computer is a machine compile

second.txt:

and coding,

is a machine

Answer (score 0):

В задаче сказано, что между словами могут быть несколько пробелов, и, наверняка, количество этих пробелов нужно сохранять. Логика вашего кода не соответствующая, и вы слишком много объектов подключаете к программе. Не константный объект `std::string` самостоятельно может преобразовать себя, а если использовать строковой поток для разделения строки на слова, то не так просто сохранять количество пробелов, при считывании слов. Использовать вектор для хранения этих строк, тоже не нужно, потому что файл может быть слишком большой, к тому же(если даже найдется столько памяти для вектора) это совершенно лишнее. Лучше найти, сравнивать и удалять функциями_членами самого строкового объекта, и сразу  записать результат в другой файл. Тогда в программе нужен будет только один строковой объект, ваши объекты файловых потоков и вызов функции, которая удаляет все не нужные слова из строки. Например такая функция, которая допускает, что строка не пустая, и что в строке не будут в конце пробелы(просто не зачем лишний раз выполнять эти проверки), так как в задаче вы вводите всю строку из файла, и там не будут завершающих пробелов.

```
using std::string;
void redo(string& s)
{      
    size_t k = s.size() - 1;        
    while (s[k] != ' ') --k;
    //теперь к это позиция последнего пробела перед последным словом
    // строка сравнения
    string t = s.substr(k + 1, 3);  
    // позиции начала и конца слова
    size_t first = s.find_first_not_of(' '),
        second = s.find_first_of(' ', first);
    //насколько я понял, последнее слово не нужно удалять   
    while (second != s.npos) {  // пока это не последнее слово  
        //если первые 3 буквы совпадают
        if (s.substr(first, 3) == t) {
            //удаляем second - first элементов, начиная от позиции first
            s.erase(first, second - first); 
            //и ищем позицию элемента не пробела
            while (s[first] == ' ')
                ++first;
        }
        //иначе ищем позицию начала следующего слова
        // начиная c позиции конца текущего слова
        else
           first = s.find_first_not_of(' ', second );
        //определяем позицию конца следующего слова     
        second = s.find_first_of(' ', first);       
    }   
    //и, если нужно, чтобы в начале не было пробелов, то
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(' '));
}
```

Таким образом мы сохранили количество пробелов между словами. Теперь вся программа такая:

```
int main()
{   
    string line;
    std::ifstream myfirst("misal.txt"); 
    std::ofstream mysecond ("second.txt");
    //тут проверка на открытие

    while (std::getline(myfirst, line))
    {
        redo(line);
        // записываем результат
        mysecond << line << '\n';
    }
    //и закрываем файлы 
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но имелось ввиду немножко другое:Начальный текст ( first.txt), а измененный текст (second.txt) . Вот например: 

        `      
        first.txt: 
        Programming and coding, program \n (2-строка)
        computer is a machine compile 
       
        second.txt: 
        and coding,\n(2-строка)  
        is a machine 
     
        `

Comment: Нужно обеих удалить.